# How to remove a problematic extension from VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I had the `vscode-icons` extension installed but have removed it after it started producing this message in the bottom right of Visual Studio Code's window:

```
The below 1 extension(s) in workspace recommendations have issues:
robertohuertasm.vscode-icons (not found in marketplace)
```

How can I completely remove it and any mention of it?

Comment: Just for the record, the correct id for that extension is `vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error indicates that the workspace you are opening [is recommending](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_workspace-recommended-extensions) an extension that does not exist.

The recommended extensions are listed in the `.vscode/extensions.json` file in the workspace. Just remove `"robertohuertasm.vscode-icons"` from that list